# Separar una cadena por espacios en C

Tags: array, c, string

El problema consiste en printear unos números por pantalla. Estos números se pasan por un fichero de números y caracteres.
Cuando encuentra una palabra el programa printea los numeros que ha leido hasta el momento y para. No se me permite usar fscanf para leer el fichero.

Mi primera idea ha sido crear un string:

`char cadena[1000];`

Y luego con scanf meter el texto del fichero en cadena

`scanf("%[^ECF]*s",cadena);`

Ahora cadena tiene todo el texto del fichero en un solo string, ¿habría una forma de separar este string en un array de strings que separe por espacios los elementos, para que usando atoi pueda distinguir entre numeros y caracteres?

Gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final he conseguido resolverlo usando scanf para leer los datos, si scanf lee un int devuelve 1 y si lee cualquier otra cosa devuelve 0 por lo tanto en un bucle tendríamos que poner algo similar a esto

```
    if(scanf("%d",&a)==1){
    printf("%d ", a);}
    else if(scanf("%d",&a)==0){
    break
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Usa `strtok` para separar los datos por espacios y `sscanf` para verificar si se leyó un número:

```
for (char *buffer = strtok(cadena, " "); buffer; buffer = strtok(NULL, " "))
{
    int numero;
    if (sscanf(buffer, "%d", &numero) == 1)
        printf("%d\n", numero);
    else
        break;
}
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY/RTsMgFIavOU/xB6OhZprSOp2p9QkW77xSLxiFjWyjC6VXZs9ewWo0XBD@/zvfCfpmq/U0XTivD2Nn8DTEzvW3u2f6HwXntzkjvVMBWnXGqzdZluUHWnAJiQo1llhB1qgkTiqmA1nVuFve42H1yBsi5yOOynlR0Ccx2weIb9/1ZrTWhKRKm2K/F/OCBTh40WBuf@8/6uV1vZ6ZglgSsuz349GEvskvCzEMWnkr5snEXnZ8gauZKdC2kGmUsVP6X7Qi1e8@AT99lpjDYDKxCUbtU3AmYsHEMXiUDZ2n6Qs)</kbd>.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda! me funciona casi perfecto, en el programa están puestos los números en varias lineas del fichero, cuando salta de linea se para, sabes como podría solucionarlo?

Comment: Si te fijas el separador que he especificado para `strtok` ha sido el espacio (`" "`), si en lugar de separados por espacios los números están separados por líneas prueba usar el salto de línea como separador: `(char *buffer = strtok(cadena, "\n"); buffer; buffer = strtok(NULL, "\n"))`.

Comment: Entiendo lo que me quieres decir pero el caso es que los separadores pueden ser espacios o saltos de linea y eso es lo que no se gestionar

Comment: ¿Te refieres a que los datos pueden estar indistintamente separados en líneas o separados por espacios **en el mismo archivo**?

Comment: justo eso, un ejempo del fichero sería:

1 2 3\n 4 fin